# Excel opening CSV with wrong encoding

Tags: c#, .net, excel, csv

This is partly a question for the Microsoft forums too, but I think there might be some coding involved.

We have a system built in C# .NET that generates CSV files. However, we have problems with special characters "æÆøØåÅ". The thing is, when I open the file in NotePad, everything is correct. But when I open the file in Excel, these characters are wrong. If I open in NotePad and save without actually doing any changes, it works in Excel. But I dont understand why? Is there some hidden information added to the file that can we adjusted in our C# code to make it correct in the first place?

There are other questions like this, but all answers I could find are workarounds for when you already have a wrong CSV file. In our case, we create this file, and the people we send the files too are usually not computer-people capable of changing encoding, etc.

**Edit:**

Here is the code we tried to use at the end, after generating our result CSV-string:

```
string result = "some;æøå;string";            
byte[] bytes = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(65001).GetBytes(result.ToString());
return System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(65001).GetString(bytes);
```

Comment: It may help to include your code that you're using to geenrate the file - for instance, are you passing an Encoding to the TextWriter?

Comment: Do you add the encoding to your file writing? e.g. File.WriteAllLines-Methode (String, String[], Encoding)

Comment: This sounds like a problem in the way you are encoding your CSV files, but we really can't help you unless we know how you're doing that. To answer your questions, we'd need to see the method you use to write a line of data to your CSV file. Probably something like TextWriter.WriteLine.

Comment: Make sure that code that generates the file uses an Encoding that includes the BOM (byte order mark).  For example, the  `System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(filePath, stringArray)` method uses UTF8 w/o BOM encoding.

Comment: Thank you all for comments, I understand I missed out on an essential part (I didnt think this mattered, cause we have tried many encodings with the exact same result, and I cant really see anywhere in the file where it says anything about encoding). I will find and add thie missing code-snippet when I get back to work :)